# PowerShell rename files with XML

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename

Currently I have a folder `C:\Call Archive\` with a XML file name `index.xml` and a ton of `.wav` files all with names that do not mean anything when you look at it. Names like `AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623089222.5534.WAV`

What I would like to do is take the XML structure and rename each `.wav` file based on the tags in XML.

Source Data:

```
<all>
  <recording_index recapp_id="" recapp_name="" last_generated="0">
    <day_index date="2021-06-07">
      <recording target_name="Unknown recording" filename="warning%3A" filesize="0" date="1969-12-31 19:00" source="" destination=""/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623089222.5534.WAV" filesize="40K" date="2021-06-07 14:07" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623089304.5536.WAV" filesize="42K" date="2021-06-07 14:08" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091000.5538.WAV" filesize="11K" date="2021-06-07 14:36" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091138.5540.WAV" filesize="14K" date="2021-06-07 14:39" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091201.5542.WAV" filesize="14K" date="2021-06-07 14:40" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091227.5544.WAV" filesize="43K" date="2021-06-07 14:41" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091276.5546.WAV" filesize="31K" date="2021-06-07 14:41" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
    </day_index>
  </recording_index>
</all>
```

The ideal filename should be `06-07-2021_John Doe_5555512345.wav`. Note that if possible the date would be in **`MM-DD-YYYY`** format.

Anything would help!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please update your question with your attempt.

Comment: I have a version of the code that works in CMD Prompt but was looking to have it all in one PowerShell script. I am putting together a script that will move and unpack a zip file. This is the only piece that I’m “missing”. So to answer your question of what I’ve tried, there hasn’t been anything I’ve tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop through and do the renames. Something like below:

```
# Establishing test data:
$XML = 
@"
<all>
  <recording_index recapp_id="" recapp_name="" last_generated="0">
    <day_index date="2021-06-07">
      <recording target_name="Unknown recording" filename="warning%3A" filesize="0" date="1969-12-31 19:00" source="" destination=""/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623089222.5534.WAV" filesize="40K" date="2021-06-07 14:07" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623089304.5536.WAV" filesize="42K" date="2021-06-07 14:08" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091000.5538.WAV" filesize="11K" date="2021-06-07 14:36" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091138.5540.WAV" filesize="14K" date="2021-06-07 14:39" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091201.5542.WAV" filesize="14K" date="2021-06-07 14:40" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091227.5544.WAV" filesize="43K" date="2021-06-07 14:41" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1623091276.5546.WAV" filesize="31K" date="2021-06-07 14:41" source="John Doe" destination="5555512345"/>
    </day_index>
  </recording_index>
</all>
"@

$XML = [XML]$XML

# This is the real work:
$xml.all.recording_index.day_index.recording |
ForEach-Object{
    $Date = (Get-Date $_.Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
    $Newname = "{0}_{1}_{2}.{3}" -f $Date, $_.source, $_.destination, $_.filename.Split('.')[-1]
    $Newname
    Rename-Item -Path $_.filename -NewName $Newname
}
```

For each XML element you're interested in you're just taking the properties and  concatenating them to get the new name, then just execute the rename with `Rename-Item`. I'm a little skeptical about the file locations as the full path of the original files isn't in the XML.  You may need to run from or CD to the directory with the files.

I'm also concerned about naming collisions.  I can't tell if that's a function of this being merely sample data, if is a problem you may need to get more granular with the time stamp to ensure unique file names.